# Calling FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId() on logout to stop FCM notification in Xamarin.Android would throw an exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a *Xamarin.Forms v4.4.0.991477* application in which I have setup *Firebase Push Notification*. For the *Xamarin.Android* project I have used, *Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging v71.1740.0* package.

On login the user out, I invoke,

`FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId()`

but it *throws* an exception,

```
Java.IO.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <af1c6fdcff1a4da4a0e44a8cdef352da>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <af1c6fdcff1a4da4a0e44a8cdef352da>:0 
  at Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.DeleteInstanceId () [0x0000a] in <86531d1309d7458994f8292b9231bad1>:0 
  at MyDroid.Droid.PlatformFCM.Terminate () [0x00002] in /Volumes/MyDroid/Droid/PlatformFCM.cs:40 
  --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---
java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.deleteInstanceId(Unknown Source:69)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.onClick(ButtonRenderer.java:104)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

and the token doesn't seem to expire either. I get the same token when I check the token.

How can I delete the `FirebaseInstanceId` to expire the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call,

`FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId();`

should be invoked in the background thread like this,

`Task.Run(() => { FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId(); });`

because it is a **blocking service**. It should **not** be called on the `Main` thread.

[Reference,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-void-deleteinstanceid-)

> public void **deleteInstanceId ()**
>
> Delete the Instance ID and the data associated with it.
>
> This stops the periodic sending of data to the Firebase backend started when the Instance ID was generated, unless another library that requires InstanceId (like FCM, RemoteConfig or Analytics) is used or it's configured to be executed automatically.
>
> A new Instance ID is generated asynchronously if Firebase Cloud Messaging auto-init is enabled.
>
> *This is a blocking function so do not call it on the main thread.*